# Is this pg query correct in node express.js?

Tags: sql, angularjs, express, pg

> I'm trying this query via pg, node, express.

```
'DELETE * FROM "Soggetto" WHERE Id IN "'+strID+'"'
```

> strID is a variable string with id separated by comma.
>   Output is Error near *.

Comment: it should be delete from .. no *

Comment: Sorry can you be more clear?

Comment: it should be delete from whatever where condition, no *

Comment: DELETE FROM not DELETE * FROM

Answer (score 2):

You are using incorrect syntax for `DELETE`.

Use this:

```
'DELETE FROM Soggetto WHERE Id IN ("'+strID+'")'
```

Comment: Deleted the *. Now the error is:
error near ""77,76,78"" ..the content of the variable.

Comment: Remove quotes around table name

Comment: Updated the query. Try now.

Comment: Can you please paste the query with string also?

Comment: Please paste query with strID value also.

Comment: 'DELETE FROM Soggetto WHERE Id IN " '+strID+' "'
If i delete the  double quotes from strID;int the output instead of 77,76,78 i've got just 76.... so strange.

Comment: you have to use parenthesis around strID. I updated the answer.

Comment: Like this IN ('1')

Comment: OK the right version it seems to be this one:
'DELETE FROM "Soggetto" WHERE Id IN ('+strID+')'
now i have a constraits violation that means the query is good i think.
Thanks @Abhilekh